# How do I retrieve an apk keyhash for facebook SSO?

Tags: android, facebook, openssl, single-sign-on

I have an app deployed on Goole's Play Store that uses Facebook SSO login. The main problem is that I haven't checked the keyhash before submitting it and I don't have the computer I made that build with anymore (therefore no debug.keystore, but I still have the certificate I signed the apk with).

I tried to unzip the APK, go to META-INF and extract the file CERT.RSA... from there I used the command: keytool -printcert -file CERT.RSA | openssl sha1 -binary | openssl base64

but the output is wrong (it's a keyhash I already have in the facebook app settings).

I would like to avoid making an update just for that problem, considering I could solve it just setting the right keyhash in the facebook app settings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ok, the problem was the alias inside the certificate. Found the right one to use, everything worked as a charm.

The final command line was:

```
keytool -exportcert -alias user_alias -keystore dev_certificate | openssl sha1 -binary | openssl base64
```

Comment: What user_alias u used ? Cause I have propably similar problem and my fb login with ganareted hash_key doesn't work, wrong user_alias can be the source of this issue? my question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22580060/how-properly-generate-fb-keyhash-to-make-login-works-on-apk-file

Answer (score 0):

If you log into developer.facebook.com and view your apps (Click on "Apps" on the top)

Select the app you want to find the Hash-Key for (From the left)

Click on "Edit Settings" in the settings panel.

Scroll down until you see the "Native Android App" panel, in there you should find the "Android Key Hash"

I hope this solves your problem.

Comment: Nope. My problem is that I'm missing the key that I need to put there to enable SSO Login.

Comment: If you connect your device to the computer while eclipse is running and try logging into your app with Facebook's SSO, an error will appear in logcat, in that error the correct Hash Key will be displayed

Comment: true, but it gives me a different keyhash than the required one.

Comment: Are you running the correct version of the app? Try adding that hash to developer.facebook.com and see what happens.