# How properly generate fb keyhash to make login works on .apk file

Tags: android, eclipse, facebook

my problem is that fb login works properly when my app is installed on my phone by debbuging in eclipse.When I try to install it by exported .apk file, I get the message: "app would like to get access to your public profile and list of friends" if i click ok nothing happens.

I create [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22544573/fb-login-crashes-when-i-install-app-by-exported-apk) the question and in comment I read the suggestion that I should generate another hash key for my .apk file.

Firstly I go to eclipse->  right click on my project -> android tools -> Export signed application package

Secondly I found the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11864700/signed-apk-has-different-key-hash-for-facebook), how to get the hash key for signed facebook apk.

My keystore which I create during the exporting project to file is there:
C:\Users\Group\Desktop\albert\ and is named by keystore, so I write this lines in command prompt

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_51\bin>keytool -exportcert -alias keystore
-keystore "C:\Users\Group\Desktop\albert\keystore" | "C:\OpenSSL\bin\openssl"
sha1 -binary | "C:\OpenSSL\bin\openssl" base64
```

I was asked for password and typed this one which I used for creating keystore. Then I get the hashcode, but after putting it into facebook developer panel, the login still doesn't work.

How to solve this login problem? This issue make me sick :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mistake was in alias, when you create new keystore file during exporting your app, you need to  give a alias this which I mark. This same name you need to put to your command prompt.

[image]

so not as I done, cause I put my file name "keystore" but put there your alias name and everything will be alright